# 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am a newbie to WCF and I am doing self-studies by creating sample applications. This is a code from a very simple application, which throws an exception form following line which lays under the comment

```
namespace ConsoleAppHost
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {    
            //Exception thorwing from following line
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ReportService.ReportService))) //Exception thorwn from this
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Host started @ " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my app.config file from host (the same console application). Pleases be kind enough to show me where the issue is?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="ReportService.ReportService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
      <endpoint address="ReportService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingconfiguration="" contract="ReportService.IReportService"></endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress ="http://localhost:8080/"/>
          <add baseAddress ="net.tcp://localhost:8090/"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</configuration>
```

**Here is the source code to have a look if you are really interested.**

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F1C4404429DCCB7F!17480&authkey=!ABb-N4DexoIFGqw&ithint=file%2czip

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

1. Location of `<services>` section in the configuration file: it has to be inside `<system.serviceModel>`.
2. `bindingconfiguration` attribute is misspelled. It must be `bindingConfiguration`.

Here is the way you can find this out: indeed the exception is thrown at the line you pointed out. And this was `TypeInitializationException`. If you drill down into `InnerException` fields then you can finally see plain message like "Unrecognized attribute ".

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I do the changes as you mentioned. Thanks again for giving me even more details. They are really important to me.